# How to update collection in cassandra whose key is timestamp type

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, nosql

I am trying to update 'map' column, but an attempt of doing so resulting in error:

**Error:**

```
error: database errorTypeError: Not a valid bigint, expected Long/Number/Buffer, obtained '2014-12-07T13:53:10.658Z'
```

**Attempt**

```
var query_attendance = 'UPDATE emp_attendance SET attendace = attendace + ? where year = ? and month = ? and emp_id = ?';
var udpateAttendance = function(empId, timestampMillis, cb){
    var foundDate = new Date(timestampMillis);
    var year = foundDate.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = foundDate.getUTCMonth();
    var date = foundDate.getUTCDate();
    var attendace = {};
    attendace['2014-12-07T13:53:10.658Z'] = 'Present';
//  winston.info('attendace' + JSON.stringify(foundDate));
    var values = [attendace, year, month, empId];
    var options = {
        hints: ['map','int','int','int'],
        prepare: true
    };
    winston.info('Values: ' + JSON.stringify(values));
    client.execute(query_attendance, values, options, function(err, resultSet){
        winston.info('Query Completed');
        if(err){
            winston.error('database error' + err);
            cb(err, null);
            return;         
        }
        winston.info('Query successful');
        cb(null, resultSet);
    });
}
```

**My View:**

I think i need to tell the driver that type of key in map collection is timestamp type, but i  am not finding how to specify such input to driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of debugging into cassandra driver library, i eventually found what mistake was there.

When an input of type date is received by 'encoder.js' in 'cassandra-driver' then 'encodeTimestamp()' checks for type using 'instanceof' keyword.
This is the point where my mistake resulted in error, since

```
attendace[foundDate]
or 
attendace['2014-12-07T13:53:10.658Z']
```

are possibly making key as of type 'string' (being js newbie, can not confirm it). 
So, the solution to problem is, `i need to pass date object as key of attendace variable`.

**Note:**

Although, i am still unable to pass date as object as key for another object, but that's different question altogether.
Just to keep running the flow ( till i found way to pass date as object), i made a small change in 'encodeTimestamp()' of 'encoder.js' in cassandra driver.
Change

```
  function encodeTimestamp (value, type) {
    console.log('Encoding time stamp: ' + value + '\ttype:'+type);
    //parsing the date object, 
    var convertedDate = new Date(value);
    // check if supplied value is converted into date, if so, assign its value to value variable and continue with original process
    if((convertedDate) && (convertedDate!= NaN)){
      value = convertedDate;
    }
    if (value instanceof Date) {
      console.log('Value is date ');
      value = value.getTime();
    }else{
      console.log('input value ' + value + ' is not a date');
    }
    return encodeBigNumber (value, type);
  }
```

`This is hack only`, so i am hoping there must be some genuine solution and some one will come  up with that,

Comment: It is not possible as is, I've created a [Jira ticket for it](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-57)

Comment: Just to get my work done as of now, is my solution to problem correct or it will impact other queries or process in API

Comment: The solution is correct and it should not affect other parts of your application.